# Bash alias para criar script executavél

Tags: bash

Quero criar um alias para fazer um script executável, já tentei adicionar ao `.bash_aliases` e ao `.bashrc`

**comando:** `alias mksh='touch $1 && chmod +x $1'`

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Wosss, isso...acho que a melhor maneira é transformar em função, já que "alias" não entende os parâmetros posicionais

Comment: meee não funciona no zsh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use alias + function:

```
alias mksh='function __mksh() { touch $*; chmod +x $*; }; __mksh'
```

inclusive pode utilizar vários argumentos, como: mksh file1 file2 file3